# Using Virtual Button to control Multiple Image Object behavior

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am trying to create track two image object for one AR camera from Vuforia in Unity. I want to create two Image Objects under it. One of them is with a virtual button. Another one will have an animation object on it. I am trying to push the virtual button on object one to trigger the motion of object two. I can achieve it if the button and the animation are in the same image object. I am not sure how can I do it if the button and the animation are under different image object. If possible, how should I do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain a bit further what exactly is supposed to happen? Additionally avoid asking `Is it possible?` since the answer is mostly `Yes.` .. the question is rather **How?**. Please also add what you researched and tried so far since currently your question would also be to broad. Refer to [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your comment. This is the first time I post. I will modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can. I figured out. You just need to find the Gameobject by name as most online tutorials do although their Gameobject is under the same image object.

Answer (score 1):

To control a gameObject from another you need to have communication between both.

```
MyScriptOne

MyScriptTwo
```

Inside the scripts you can add a public reference like this:

```
public MyScriptTwo myScriptTwo;
```

And then when you click a button in `MyScriptOne` you can call anything `public` in `MyScriptTwo` like this.

```
myScriptTwo.TriggerAnimation ();
```

The fact that they are not active at the same time does not mean they can't be connected, in fact you should verify that the animated object is active before animating it, since the button will trigger the function anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind, that default vuforia behaviour does not specify which image target is tracked, by default vuforia only set active all components under your image target. To achieve different behaviours on your image targets you should create your own script with custom behaviour. Some example:

```
public class VuforiaCustomBehaviour: MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
public TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
void Start()
{

    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }
}

public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    {
        if (mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName == "marker1")
        {
           DoSmth();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        OnTrackingLost();
    }
}
```

Also you should disable default trackable events handler and add this to your image target.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use almost the same structure implemented this. I am curious what's the usage of the "mTrackableBehavior" here? What is the "TrackableName"? Is it a name we used in Unity as the object name?

Comment: mTrackableBehaviour its component on imagetarget called ImageTargetBehaviour. We get states from ITrackableEventHandler interface. "TracableName" is name of imagetarget in your database. Like default is "Astronaut".